# Trying to style a single cell in a table, answers found, but nothing works

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table in mobile on my website, www.airfieldcards.com and when you look at any of the airfields on a mobile, the last cell is a telephone number.  I want to style this with the following added to the bottom of my css file.

```css
#telephone
{
background-color:#3C3;
 color:#white;
 border:1px color:#3C3;
 border-radius:5px;
 padding:15px;
 text-decoration:none;
```

I have added the following into my html / php... but it doesn't work.  This has been put into the bottom of the bootstrap css.

```html
<td class="text-right"><h4>PPR Number</h4></td>
  
  <td id="telephone"><h4><?php  echo cr($rs["PPR_number"]); ?></h4></td>
```

Nothing I have tried styles it at all except the a: at the beginning of the huge bootstrap css file. The telephone number calls the "number" if clicked on by the user on a modern phone.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your code in action, rather than the snippets you feel are relevant?  With the exception of `#white` being an invalid color declaration, the CSS you've provided here applies to `#telephone` as expected.

Comment: I've changed it to this as mentioned below, but still nothing.
table > tbody > tr > td#telephone
{
background-color:#3C3;
 color:#FFF;
 border:1px color:#3C3;
 border-radius:5px;
 padding:15px;
 text-decoration:none;
}

Comment: That's because that answer is wrong. Here is your code in Bootply (with `#white` corrected).  It's functioning as expected; if you're not seeing this on your end it has to be because some code you HAVEN'T shown us is interfering: https://www.bootply.com/LbDRgm5Avy

Answer (score 1):

OK, so, you are talking about the following page:
http://www.airfieldcards.com/b/index.php?a=a&f=376

The spot with the phone number is like this and is missing the id="telephone" in the td tag:

```
<tr>
  <td class="text-right"><h4>PPR Number</h4></td>
  <td class="text-left"><strong><a href="tel:+353 86 8497878">+353 86 8497878</a></strong></td>
 </tr>
```

After fixing the above, using the following CSS will work just fine:

```
td#telephone {
    background-color: #3C3;
    color: white;
    border: 1px #3C3 solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Rlessard.  That hasn't worked either.

Comment: Can you provide me with a link where this is in action? where the TD tags have the ID attribute properly assigned?

Answer (score 0):

you need to correct the styles only

```
 #telephone
        {
            background-color:#3C3;
            color:white;
            border:1px #3C3 solid;
            border-radius:5px;
            padding:15px;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
```

and to make sure it dosn't overwrite by other styles 
change the id to

```
table > tbody > tr > td#telephone {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer samehanwar, I've tried that, still nothing.

Comment: is this style is only needed for the mobile version ?

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't really matter if it wasn't, and showed up on the full size website version.

Comment: yes it sometimes happens , because bootstrap overwrite its styles   try this .table > tbody > tr > td#telephone {  } . it should works

Comment: ID specificity outweighs attribute specificity; Bootstrap's base CSS is not the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input samehanwar, but it's still the same.  It's driving me mad, it should work, but doesn't.

Comment: try to put the styles in the head of the webpage.                                <style> .table > tbody > tr > td#telephone {
            background-color:#3C3;
        }
      </style>

Comment: Thanks for that, I've tried it within <style> tags at the top of the website, and still nothing.  See http://www.airfieldcards.com/b/index.php?a=r&f=1

Comment: if this is the page that you have the problem with . i can not see the ID #telephone in the page

Comment: assign the ID to the element you want to style

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your css into a custom file and then referencing that file below the bootstrap css file or cdn (whichever you are using) on your site? For instance, if you saved the css in a file called "custom_style.css" in a "content" folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/content/custom_style.css">
```

It is best to not edit the bootstrap files directly if you can help it.

Comment: No, I haven't Tyler Rousseau, thanks for the tip.  I'll give it a try when I get home at lunch time tomorrow.  I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: Yes, I'm guilty of editing the bootstrap file directly, but simply added some styling at the end.  Being at the end of the cascade... as it were.

Comment: You will make your life easier in the long run and make your code more maintainable by others as well.